# A counter example for proving Schmidt Decompostion doesn't hold in general for tri-partite systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, linear-algebra

I have been trying hard at this. Schmidt decomposition in bi-partite systems itself is pretty unintuitive for me.

I have tried to understand two different proofs and I followed one well, but just wasn't able to understand the concept intuitively. The question I am stuck at is in Nielsen and Chuang (10th-anniversary edition, pg 110, prob 2.77), which asks me to show by counter-example that, in general, the Schmidt decomposition doesn't hold for tripartite systems.

Can anyone please provide a counter-example, or at least some intuitive understanding of thet Schmidt decomposition? As I said, I already followed a proof well, I am looking for more of a practical/concrete understanding rather than an abstract proof.

Comment: Please add the specific reference (edition, page number /exercise number, equation). Additionally, could you elaborate on what exactly is your problem, i.e. what concept you do not understand?

Comment: Okay, I am editing the post, thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/183000/why-schmidt-decomposition-only-holds-for-two-component-composite-systems?rq=1) and the references therein help?

Comment: the Schmidt decomposition can certainly be applied to tripartite systems. One just needs to remember that it can only be applied to *bipartitions* of it. In other words, given a tripartite $\Psi_{ABC}$, you can consider the Schmidt decomposition of $A$ vs $BC$, etc.

Comment: @Jakob I already read that post, but it is too abstract for me, I didn't get much from that

Answer (score 1):

To help understand Schmidt decomposition (of a bipartite state) it is first essential to review the singular value decomposition (SVD) of an arbitrary $m\times n$ matrix. Since you have already seen Nielsen and Chuang's discussion, I would recommend looking at the discussion of SVD in Mikio Nakahara's *Quantum Computing: From Linear Algebra to Realizations*. Their approach is quite different from the one presented in Nielsen and Chuang and gives you a different perspective on what SVD is.

In any case, let $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{H}_A\otimes\mathcal{H}_B\otimes\mathcal{H}_C$ denote a Hilbert space of tripartite states where each subspace $\mathcal{H}_i$ is two-dimensional. Then I think the state

$$|\psi\rangle_{ABC}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |001\rangle_{ABC} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |010\rangle_{ABC}$$
is an example of a state that does not admit a Schmidt decomposition. This is because of a theorem in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9911073) which states that *any tripartite state $|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ admits a Schmidt decomposition if and only if the "partial inner products" of $|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ with the basis vectors of $\mathcal{H}_A$ $(\{|i\rangle_A\})$ yield bipartite states $|\psi_i\rangle_{BC}\equiv \hphantom{}_A\langle i|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ whose Schmidt number is one.*

If we compute $\hphantom{}_A\langle i|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ for the example above we obtain

$$\begin{aligned}
|\psi_0\rangle_{BC}&=\hphantom{}_A\langle 0|\psi\rangle_{ABC} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|01\rangle_{BC}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|10\rangle_{BC}\\
|\psi_1\rangle_{BC}&=\hphantom{}_A\langle 1|\psi\rangle_{ABC} = 0.
\end{aligned}$$
$|\psi_0\rangle_{BC}$ is a Bell state, which we recognise is entangled and therefore has Schmidt number $> 1$ so by the theorem mentioned above $|\psi\rangle_{ABC}$ should not be Schmidt decomposable.

I don't know if there is another way of showing this but I am hoping someone else can leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you! It was pretty helpful. This is one of few things for which I lack 'imagination' or 'intuition'.  I too hope someone else can put a quick answer explaining the concept intuitively.